# How to program MapList?

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, code-review

I would like to know if there is a nice functional way to code up a `MapList` which applies `f` to each element of `expr` and returns a list of the results obtained.

Here is my implementation:

```
MapList[f_, expr_] := List @@ (MapIndexed[ReplacePart[expr, #2 -> f[#1]] &, expr])
```

It works in this test case:

```
myData = head[a, b, c, d];
MapList[f, myData]

(*  {head[f[a],b,c,d], head[a,f[b],c,d], head[a,b,f[c],d], head[a,b,c,f[d]]}  *)
```

But if the `head` has some `DownValues` or funny `Attributes` like this:

```
SetAttributes[head, Flat];
MapList[f, myData]

(*  {f[a], b, c, d, a, f[b], c, d, a, b, f[c], d, a, b, c, f[d]}  *)
```

it gives the wrong result (because the `Flat` is kicking in before `List @@` swaps out the head of the output).

How do I program a `ListMap` that is as fast and robust against possible definitions attached to head?

Comment: Something like `MapAt[f,expr,#]&/@Range[Length[expr]]`?

Comment: Yup! And also the variation `Array[MapAt[f,expr,#]&,Length[expr]]` works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944549/a-maplist-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A asked something not too dissimilar some years ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944549/a-maplist-function

My implementation from the question itself:

```
MapList[f_, expr_, level_: 1] :=
 MapAt[f, expr, #] & /@
  Position[expr, _, level, Heads -> False]
```

This happens to handle your example:

```
myData = head[a, b, c, d];
SetAttributes[head, Flat];
MapList[f, myData]
```

> ```
> {head[f[a], b, c, d], head[a, f[b], c, d], head[a, b, f[c], d], head[a, b, c, f[d]]}
> ```

I suspect you may find the answers I recieved of interest as well.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that!   Please mark my question as a duplicate.  Your answer and the answers there are quite helpful.